# parameter batch_shape of tf.eye depends on placeholder variable shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

My end goal is to make the default covariance smaller by multiplying it by 0.01. In order to do this, I decided to create a simple covariance (the identity matrix) and then multiply this matrix by 0.01, to finally give it to the tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance function. The problem is that I can't initialize the parameter batch_shape when I don't know beforehand the shape. How can I workaround this?

I have the following code:

```
    self.state_in= tf.placeholder(shape=[None,s_size],dtype=tf.float32)
    self.hidden = slim.fully_connected(self.state_in,h_size,biases_initializer=None,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
    self.output = slim.fully_connected(self.hidden,a_size,activation_fn=None,biases_initializer=None)
    mean= self.output
    cov =tf.eye(4,batch_shape=[mean.shape[0]])
    normal = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
             loc=mean,
             covariance_matrix=cov*0.01)
```

This is the line it fails: `cov =tf.eye(4,batch_shape=[mean.shape[0]])`

> TypeError: **int** returned non-int (type NoneType)

*Thanks, in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Omit `batch_shape=[mean.shape[0]]`
`tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance` is smart enough to handle batches.

I was going to delete this question, but maybe somebody will find it useful.

Thanks.